# nuxt config, $route undefined?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Im getting errors in my application when im in `nuxt.config.js` try to access `this.$route`
The error im getting is: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined

Im running "nuxt": "^2.0.0"...

I've done this before in a previous application where I was able to do this, but apparently wont work in this, and I have no idea why ?

The whole code block it's concerning are:

```
 head() {
   let canonical = null;
   if (this.$route) {
     const { path } = this.$route;
     const pathWithSlash = path.endsWith('/') ? path : `${path}/`
     canonical = `${hostname}${pathWithSlash}`
   }
   .......
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. `this.$route` resolves correctly for me in `head()` of `nuxt.config.js`.

Comment: What is your exact nuxt version ? Try this command: `yarn list --pattern nuxt | grep nuxt@`

Comment: the nuxt version is 2.0.0

Comment: @envy any solution?

Comment: it happens just due to production mode